# Can Sibelius house styles be edited selectively?

Tags: sibelius

I can export house styles from Sibelius 6, but I end up with a binary `.lib` file of around 100 KB, of which the only recognisable characters are `SIBELIUS` a couple of times at the start.

Is there any way to change parts of this file selectively? For example to set the parameters of an instrument I've defined, or the layout?

It would also help with maintaining a history of house style changes by being able to use version control software on small changes, rather than on the whole binary lump.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to edit the exported .lib file. The way to make changes selectively is to edit and make changes to all the various parameters of a live Sibelius document and then export the house style.

If you have properly exported the house style, you can start with a new blank document in Sibelius based on that house style, make further edits and changes, and then export a new house style under a different name.

Please tell us exactly what version of Sibelius you are using, and whether you are on Mac or Windows.

Answer (score 0):

The House Style format has never been reverse-engineered.  But Bob Zawalich has written a plugin "Style Sheet" which "Displays which text styles, line styles, symbols, and notehead styles are being used in a score. In Sibelius 7 and later the font named and size for text items will be displayed.The main music font, document layout data, and some engraving rules data can also be displayed."
This isn't what you're asking for.  But it might enable an alternative approach to your problem.